# How can I accept the response for Dropbox while doing changes with my owner account?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, dropbox-api

According to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks, I was told that once I configured with WebHooks, any changes will be responsed to me like events..... :

[image]
Now the problem is, I passed the verification and when I add/delete a file in my owner account, no response to me. My codes are:

```
public class WebHookController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["challenge"] != null)
            {
                return Content(Request.QueryString["challenge"]);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```

So is there anything wrong? Why I didn't get any responses? Anything to SPECIALLY PAY ATTENTION TO WHILE USING THIS?

Reguards! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks your nice suggestion. I forgot to tell you that I'd been authorized successfully. The reason is that Box.NET needs a POST method in MVC. However for the 1st's verification and the 2nd one sharing the same address. I wrote the methods like below to solve my problem successfully:

```
public class WebHookController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Just for verification ONLY by "Get"
        /// </summary>
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult VerificationWebHook()
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["challenge"] != null)
            {
                return Content(Request.QueryString["challenge"]);
            }
            return Content("No challenge got, verification failed.");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// "Delta" is a customized class that indicates a user list that changes the file or do 
        /// actions to the Box.net
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Index")]
        public ActionResult NotifyWebHook(Delta userList)
        {
            return Json(userList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll only see events for users who have authorized your app. My guess is that you haven't authorized your app with your own account yet. The easiest way to do this is just to click the "generate" button on your app's page to generate an access token for your account.